# Is it possible to use postgres COPY to make a select output from one table to another text field as csv

Tags: postgresql

I've been considering exploring the options of archiving old data in a postgres system, but making it available to the system as a table. I am currently copying out to gzipped files, creating foreign data wrappers from `gunzkip -k` and leaving it at that.

This works and while retrieval can be a little slow at times it creates a lot of tables, so I thought to myself, since the files aren't overly large, could this csv be stored in toast?

Before this gets too complicated - the data would still need interesting access methods and the multiple table issue would still need answering, I did need to start somewhere so tried to run a simple copy command from table to table like so

```
COPY foo_data(data)
FROM (SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id WHERE date > now() - interval '6 months')
WITH (
    format csv,
    header true,
    null '',
    delimiter ',',
    quote '"'
)
```

Generating this errror:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id)
```

Leaving me wondering 2 things, is there an SQL statement that will output csv similar to json_agg() meaning copy is not necessary, and if not is table to table copying even possible, or would 2 copy commands (copy to file on disk, copy newly created file to other table) be required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> is there an SQL statement that will output csv similar to json_agg()

You can convert a whole row to text which will then output [a textual representation of that row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE). E.g.

```
select p::text
from person;
```

Might return something like:

```
(1, Foo, Bar)
(2, Some, "Other Name")
```

Which is already close to a "csv" format, you just need to remove the parentheses, which can be done using: `substr(p::text, 2, length(p::text) - 2)`

Using that approach, you could do:

```
insert into foo_data(data)
SELECT substr(f::text, 2, length(f::text) - 2)
FROM foo f 
ORDER BY id 
WHERE date > now() - interval '6 months');
```